# Howto capture posix_spawnp() with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: ld-preload

I am able to capture all low level functions such as open(), fopen(), etc. and call the original function using dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, “...”) but I am unable to do the same with posix_spawnp() because my executable crashes. Why is that and how to capture this function?

Sorry for the delay. Here's the code I've attempted on some embedded device running Linux:

```
int posix_spawnp(pid_t * pid, const char * file, const posix_spawn_file_actions_t * file_actions, const posix_spawnattr_t * attrp, char * const argv[], char * const envp[])
{
    orig_fopen_t orig_fopen = (orig_fopen_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    FILE * fp = orig_fopen("/tmp/DiagnosticsAgent.log", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "*** posix_spawnp(..., {");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; argv[i] != 0; ++ i)
        fprintf(fp, "%s, ", argv[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "}, ...)\n");
    fclose(fp);

    void * handle = dlopen("libpthread.so.0", RTLD_LAZY);
    orig_posix_spawnp_t orig_posix_spawnp = (orig_posix_spawnp_t)dlsym(handle, "posix_spawnp");
    return orig_posix_spawnp(pid, file, file_actions, attrp, argv, envp);
}
```

Comment: Any coded attempts? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: I’m trying to paste the following using my cell phone and the formatting is not correct:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works alright with my linux/glibc. Here's a working example:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

cat > main.c <<EOF
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int C, char **V)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if(0!=posix_spawnp(&pid,V[1],NULL,NULL,V+1,NULL))
        return 1;
    wait(0);
}
EOF
gcc main.c

cat > libspawn.c <<EOF
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <spawn.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int spawnp_signature(pid_t *pid, const char *file,
                   const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
                   const posix_spawnattr_t *attrp,
                   char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
spawnp_signature posix_spwanp;
int posix_spawnp(pid_t *pid, const char *file,
                   const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
                   const posix_spawnattr_t *attrp,
                   char *const argv[], char *const envp[])

{
    fprintf(stderr, "OVERRIDE\n");
    spawnp_signature *real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,__func__);
    return real(pid,file,file_actions,attrp,argv,envp);

}
EOF
gcc -shared -fpic -o libspawn.so libspawn.c -ldl

./a.out echo hello world
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libspawn.so ./a.out echo hello world
```

The second output is printed with the word `OVERRIDE` as expected.

EDIT: 
After making your example compilable, it works for me too. Perhaps some of the unchecked calls are failing on your machine or perhaps you've forgotten to link the `dl` library.

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

cat > main.c <<EOF
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int C, char **V)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if(0!=posix_spawnp(&pid,V[1],NULL,NULL,V+1,NULL))
        return 1;
    wait(0);
}
EOF
gcc main.c

cat > libspawn.c <<EOF
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <spawn.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int spawnp_signature(pid_t *pid, const char *file,
                   const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
                   const posix_spawnattr_t *attrp,
                   char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
spawnp_signature posix_spwanp;
int posix_spawnp(pid_t *pid, const char *file,
                   const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
                   const posix_spawnattr_t *attrp,
                   char *const argv[], char *const envp[])

{
    fprintf(stderr, "OVERRIDE\n");
    spawnp_signature *real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,__func__);
    return real(pid,file,file_actions,attrp,argv,envp);

}
EOF
cat >libspawn.c <<EOF
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <spawn.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*orig_posix_spawnp_t)(pid_t *pid, const char *file,
                   const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions,
                   const posix_spawnattr_t *attrp,
                   char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
typedef FILE *(*orig_fopen_t)(char const*, char const*);
int posix_spawnp(pid_t * pid, const char * file, const posix_spawn_file_actions_t * file_actions, const posix_spawnattr_t * attrp, char * const argv[], char * const envp[])
{
    orig_fopen_t orig_fopen = (orig_fopen_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    FILE * fp = orig_fopen("/tmp/DiagnosticsAgent.log", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "*** posix_spawnp(..., {");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; argv[i] != 0; ++ i)
        fprintf(fp, "%s, ", argv[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "}, ...)\n");
    fclose(fp);

    void * handle = dlopen("libpthread.so.0", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle) { perror(0); return -1; }
    orig_posix_spawnp_t orig_posix_spawnp = (orig_posix_spawnp_t)dlsym(handle, "posix_spawnp");
    fprintf(stderr,"OVERRIDE\t");
    return orig_posix_spawnp(pid, file, file_actions, attrp, argv, envp);
}
EOF
gcc -shared -fpic -o libspawn.so libspawn.c -ldl

./a.out echo hello world
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libspawn.so ./a.out echo hello world
```

Comment: Ok your example works on Linux x86 but not on my Linux armv7 (segfault). But you've answered my original question.

Comment: @PhilBouchard Thanks. Attempted to answer the edit too. My guess is the `dlopen` could be failing there (you are hardcoding a specific filename and that could be fragile). Perhaps check strace if you don't want to add error checks yet (but you should add error checks too).

Comment: I did try with the traditional dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "...") and I've got the same crash problem. I used dlopen() because I thought the function was located there. I'll do a general search...

Comment: ... and on Linux x86 posix_spawnp() is in libc.so.6. On the embedded device it might be elsewhere (but I can't find it easily).

Comment: One way or the other you've answered my question!